# Too many windows using Josh Smith's demo app on MVVM

Tags: mvvm

I am trying to learn MVVM. Josh's demo app seems very general, where I could create a new app by replacing the customer related classes. To this end I created a new project from scratch, using much of Josh's code. Sometimes I pasted his code into my files and sometimes I just copied a complete file. As I went along, I removed any references to the customer classes.

I must have missed something important because running the code produces two windows instead of one. I see how Josh has created a window in App.OnStartUp(). The app will create a window without this code, which is why I have two windows. I don't understand why his original demo only has one window.

After scratching my head for an hour, I think I need a hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I kept searching and found the line StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" in App.xaml. Now I only have one window.